# Angular - How to test template driven form components that are using viewProviders?

Tags: angular

We're using template driven forms on my project and some of those forms contain nested components that contain form elements. We're not using reactive forms at all, just template forms and we're using viewProviders to link the nested component's form elements to the parent form.

```
@Component({
    ...
    viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]
})
```

This all works perfectly/validates perfectly, but when I try to unit test the component I get the following error:

```
Error: 
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

      Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:

      Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
       <input formControlName="firstName">
       <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </div>
```

Like I said, minus the unit tests, this all executes/validates without error and we're not currently using reactive forms, so we're not using formGroup or formControls. Is there something I can do in the TestBed or in a Spy that'd help the component get past this error?

Comment: Please add the code that sets up your tests - I bet it's where the problem is. Also, component's template would be good to see as well. We probably don't even need the real template but it still should be good enough to clearly show the problem.

Comment: Any luck solving this? I'm having the same issue.